# Auto creation of Sales team from Account team on Opportunity creation

Tags: trigger, process-builder, visual-workflow

I want to copy Account Team & Account Share records to Opportunity team & Opportunity Share objects while creating a new opportunity.

I have accomplished this by writing a trigger. Anyhow I want to achieve this with out writing code. Can any one please suggest me some alternate ways?
It would much better If possible to achieve it using flows.

Thanks,
Karthik